# Extracting string from file address

Tags: php, string, extract, explode

I have string like "/files/temp/**ABCD**xyz-dfgdf.jpg"

I need to extract ABCD. 
First I'm trying to get the whole filename with this

```
$file="/files/temp/ABCDxyz-dfgdf.jpg";
$fileName=explode("files/temp/",$file)[0];
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What other string formats would there be? If they are all in the same format as you mentioned in your question then you could use a combination of explode() and substr() to extract that string.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying explode, but it's not working. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Edit: use basename() instead of explode() for dynamic file names/paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to get the filename without the directory:

```
$filename = basename($file); // => ABCDxyz-dfgdf.jpg
$beginning = substr($filename, 0, 4); // => ABCD
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the **first four caracters** of the filename ?

If you have a path :

```
$path = '/files/temp/ABCDxyz-dfgdf.jpg';
```

You can get the filename with substr :

```
$filename = basename($path);
```

And then extract the four first chars :

```
$firstFour = substr($filename,0,4);
echo $firstFour;
```

Answer (score 1):

The below piece of code results in

**ABCDxyz-dfgdf.jpg**

you can go ahead from here on extracting **ABCD**

```
    $name = "/files/temp/ABCDxyz-dfgdf.jpg";

    $temp = explode("/files/temp/",$name);

    print "\n".$temp[1]; // give out ABCDxyz-dfgdf.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to get first four characters after path

```
$str = "/files/temp/ABCDxyz-dfgdf.jpg";
preg_match_all('/files\/temp\/([a-z]{4})/i',$str,$m);
echo $m[1][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
<?php

// your file
$file = '/files/temp/ABCDxyz-dfgdf.jpg';
$info = pathinfo($file);
$file_name =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);
echo $file_name; 
$firstFour = substr($file_name,0,4);
echo $firstFour;

?>
```

**Output:-**

> Your File path:-  ABCDxyz-dfgdf
>
> REQUIRED OUTPUT: ABCD

reference Example : [Cilck Here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wUIIS9)